# Adding a new column to a multiIndex dataframe, using another dataframe with different column size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following multiIndex dataframe:

```
df= 
        id/uniqueID       var1    var2    var3   
        5171/0            10.0    2.8     0.0   
        5171/1            40.9    2.5     3.4   
        5171/2            60.7    3.1     5.2   
        ...
        5171/57           0.5     1.3     5.1   
        4567/0            1.5     2.0     1.0   
        4567/1            4.4     2.0     1.3   
        4567/2            6.3     3.0     1.5   
        ...
        4567/57           0.7     1.4     1.6   
       ... 
        9584/0            0.3     2.6     0.0   
        9584/1            0.5     1.2     8.3   
        9584/2            0.7     3.0     5.6   
        ...
        9584/57           0.7     1.3     0.1   

indexes_df= 
        id              labeled_idxs
        5171            [0,1,3,6,49,50]
        4567            [45,46,47,56,57]
        9584            [21]
        ...
```

I need to add a new binary column to `df` with `1` or `True` for the indexes labeled in the second dataframe, `indexes_df`, like this:

```
df= 
        id/uniqueID       var1    var2    var3    labels
        5171/0            10.0    2.8     0.0       1
        5171/1            40.9    2.5     3.4       1
        5171/2            60.7    3.1     5.2       0
        ...
        5171/57           0.5     1.3     5.1       0
        4567/0            1.5     2.0     1.0       0
        4567/1            4.4     2.0     1.3       0   
        4567/2            6.3     3.0     1.5       0   
        ...
        4567/56           0.4     0.4     1.3       1
        4567/57           0.7     1.4     1.6       1   
       ... 
        9584/0            0.3     2.6     0.0       0   
        9584/1            0.5     1.2     8.3       0   
        9584/2            0.7     3.0     5.6       0   
        ...
        9584/21           2.7     0.0     0.6       1
        ...
        9584/57           0.7     1.3     0.1       0
```

I tried to do it with the following code and similar approaches but they all failed with `SyntaxError`:

```
df['labes'] = indexes_df['labeled_idxs'].apply(lambda x: [i>0 ? 1 : 0 for i in x]))
```

How can I get the results I need?

Comment: It seems dupe is incorrect, my answer was edited (I miss first columns are indexes in both)

Comment: @jezrael ah ok! I was struggling to implement your solution! Let me try again! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is problematic, because also if correct `apply` part like another answers still is problem with:

```
df['labes'] = indexes_df['labeled_idxs']
```

because here for processing need `labeled_idxs` like another column in `df` DataFrame or index of `indexes_df` has to be same like `df`. If not, there are set values only for rows if index values are same in both `DataFrames.

---

Here is better use pure pandas solution - first [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) column filled by lists to rows and convert to strings:

```
indexes_df = indexes_df.explode('labeled_idxs')
print (indexes_df)
     labeled_idxs
id               
4567           45
4567           46
4567           47
4567           56
4567           57
          ...
5171            3
5171            6
5171           49
5171           50
9584           21

[62 rows x 1 columns]
```

---

UPDATE: Since `df` is a multiIndex dataframe, the following should work

```
indexes_df = indexes_df.explode('labeled_idxs').astype(int)
indexes_df['labels'] = 1
indexes_df.set_index('labeled_idxs', append=True, inplace=True)
df['labels'] = 0  
df.loc[indexes_df.index, indexes_df.columns] = indexes_df
```

---

OLD ANSWER:

Then join `index` and column of `DataFrame` to `Series` like:

```
s = indexes_df.index.astype(str) + '/' + indexes_df['labeled_idxs'].astype(str)
print (s)
id
4567    4567/45
4567    4567/46
4567    4567/47
4567    4567/56
4567    4567/57

5171     5171/3
5171     5171/6
5171    5171/49
5171    5171/50
9584    9584/21
Length: 62, dtype: object
```

And last compare column `id/uniqueID` by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with cast boolean mask to integers:

```
df['labes'] = df.index.isin(s).astype(int)
print (df)
             var1  var2  var3  labes
id/uniqueID                         
5171/0       10.0   2.8   0.0      1
5171/1       40.9   2.5   3.4      1
5171/2       60.7   3.1   5.2      0
5171/57       0.5   1.3   5.1      0
4567/0        1.5   2.0   1.0      0
4567/1        4.4   2.0   1.3      0
4567/2        6.3   3.0   1.5      0
4567/57       0.7   1.4   1.6      1
9584/0        0.3   2.6   0.0      0
9584/1        0.5   1.2   8.3      0
9584/2        0.7   3.0   5.6      0
9584/57       0.7   1.3   0.1      0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fails at the join step: `s = indexes_df['id'] + '/' + indexes_df['labeled_idxs']` with this error: `Ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('U21'))`. I tried to cast the values to string like: `s = str(indexes_df['id']) + '/' + str(indexes_df['labeled_idxs'])` but it creates `s` as a string with weird values...

Comment: @Birish - Sorry, 4 minutes ago my answer was edited.

Comment: my `df` dataframe is a multiIndex dataframe with two levels. I should have mentioned it in the question to avoid confusion, sorry. Here is how I managed to get the desired results: ` indexes_df = indexes_df.explode('labeled_idxs').astype(int) `
  `indexes_df['labels'] = 1 ` 
`indexes_df.set_index('labeled_idxs', append=True, inplace=True) ` 
`df['labels'] = 0 ` 
`df.loc[indexes_df.index, indexes_df.columns] = indexes_df`

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator isn't available in Python. However you could use something like that:

```py
df['labes'] = indexes_df['labeled_idxs'].apply(lambda x: [1 if i > 0 else 0 for i in x]))
```

Comment: Thanks! But now it's assigning `Nan` to all values for the new column `labels`. I think it doesn't understand that it should update the values in the related indexes of `df`

Comment: Now it's only replacing the index values in `indexes_df ` with 1! For `id=5171` it is converting `[0,1,3,6,49,50]` to `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`. It doesn't update the corresponding indexes in `df['labes']`

Answer (score 1):

You're half right. The solution is to use lambdas in list comprehension, but you've got a bit wrong. Python doesn't use ? and :, so you have to do:

```py
df['labes'] = indexes_df['labeled_idxs'].apply(lambda x: [(1 if i>0 else 0) for i in x]))
```